# Unificar dos arrays en array de objetos con formato determinado

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo dos arrays:
uno con las fechas:

```
public tiempo = [0,1.0000029056337332,2.0000058112674663,3.0000087169011995,4.0000116225349327,5.0000145281686663];
```

Otro con los valores:

`public produccion = [300,500,333,222,111,765];`

Necesito juntar en la posición 0 el valor `0,300` en la posición 1 `1.0000029056337332,500`

Es decir la posición de un array con la posición del otro, pero todo esto con la siguiente estructura:

```
resultados = [
    {
      "name": "Germany",
      "series": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "value":300
        },
        {
          "name": "1.0000029056337332",
          "value": 500
        },
        {
          "name": "2.0000058112674663",
          "value": 333
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

No tengo nada claro cómo hacer esto.

Necesito algo de ayuda.

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Este código te servirá, usando un simple [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach):

```
const tiempo =  [0,1.0000029056337332,2.0000058112674663,3.0000087169011995,4.0000116225349327,5.0000145281686663];
const produccion = [300,500,333,222,111,765];

const series = [];

tiempo.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {
    series.push({
    "name" : currentValue.toString(),
    "produccion": produccion[index]
  });
});

console.log(series);
```

En este caso la variable tiempo es un arreglo, como es un arreglo posee la propiedad "forEach", la cual utilicé para poder recorrerlo, ya que por lo visto tienes un **nombre** y a ese nombre le estás buscando el **valor**

Mientras lo recorro simplemente paso el currentValue **(valor del elemento en el arreglo)**, en este caso sería [0. 1.000.. etc]
y en el arreglo producción busco el valor que posea el mismo index **(índice)**, como lo ves aquí:

```
{
    "name" : currentValue.toString(),
    "produccion": produccion[index]
 }
```

Le agregué la función **.toString()** ya que por lo visto necesitas el campo como un texto y no como un número.

Te dejo un ejemplo en JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqe0xfmk/

Answer (score 0):

Una solución en typescript de tipo *funcional*:

```
const tiempo = [
    0,
    1.0000029056337332,
    2.0000058112674663,
    3.0000087169011995,
    4.0000116225349327,
    5.0000145281686663,
  ];
const produccion = [300, 500, 333, 222, 111, 765];

const series = tiempo.map((x, i) => ({
  name: x.toString(),
  value: produccion[i],
}));
```

Buscando una solución general, podemos definir las funciones `zipWith` y `zip` mediante tipos genéricos:

```
public zipWith<T, R, S>(as: T[], bs: R[], conv: (a: T, b: R) => S): S[] {
  return as.map((a, i) => conv(a, bs[i]));
}
public zip<T, R>(as: T[], bs: R[]) {
  return zipWith(as, bs, (a, b) => [a, b]);
}
```

Que se usaría de este modo:

```
const series = zipWith(tiempo, produccion, (a, b) => ({
  name: a.toString(),
  value: b,
}));
```